# XPath Auto Jump Between Documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

As requested, I am updating the question to include XSLT version.
My code is in .net/c#. I believe as of this year they support XSLT 3.0. The clearest statement would be that my version of XSLT is whatever the current .net core framework supports.

The result of this exercise is to be able to evaluate the code:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("http://example.com/#1111");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
string result = navigator.Evaluate("aa/bb/cc/dd"); 
// result should be "Hello"
```

If that is not possible then I am happy to do this in the context of an XSLT document. To be brief, the XSLT might look like.

```
<xsl:value-of select="aa/bb/cc/dd"/>
```

I would like to use xpath to automatically jump from one document to another. I have read the link here

[XPath - Querying two XML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904587/xpath-querying-two-xml-documents)

But, this is not quite what I am trying to accomplish.

If I have a document (http://example.com/#1111):

```
<aa>
  <bb>#1234</bb>
</aa>
```

And I have another document at, say, http://example.com/1234, that contains

```
<cc>
  <dd>Hello</dd>
</cc>
```

I would like to use the xpath:

```
aa/bb/cc/dd
```

to return "Hello".

Essentially, I would like to tell the xpath processor that if it hits an element that has a value formatted as #nnnn, that it should interpret that as a jump to another document, and should do something like doc( http://example.com/nnnn ) and continue from there.

I don't know if this is possible either by some sort of injection into the xpath parser or evaluator or some fancy xpath that looks at the value of a node and if it has a certain format then transforms it and continues.  It's also possible that maybe I can store the doc command right in the bb node so that the doc statement is already there?  I'm not certain which if any approaches could be made to work.

Any such solution would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can have a template matching an element with a value in the format of #nnnn that contains an instruction to apply templates to the corresponding document. Please edit your question and add the expected result of this exercise, and also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Michael.  I have updated the question as requested.  It sounds like you have a solution in mind, which is great news.  If I can update the question in any other way, please let me know.  There may be a delay for sleep, but I will respond first thing in the morning.

Comment: I still don't see the expected result of the XSLT transformation. There is no way that the XPath expression `aa/bb/cc/dd` will "jump" to another document; the expression expects `cc` to be a child of `bb`. The most you can achieve is have the stylesheet process the XML tree recursively, and when it gets to an element with a value that looks like a link, continue the processing in the other document - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#rule-based-processing

Comment: If you know in advance that the `bb` element contains the name of the document, you may be able to use a single expression in the form of `document(aa/bb/some-expression)/cc/dd` to return the value of `dd` in the document identified by the value of `bb`.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2 and later you can use the `doc` function and the resolve-uri function e.g.

```
doc('https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml/sample-a.xml')/aa/bb/doc(resolve-uri(., base-uri(.)))/cc/dd
```

selects the element `<dd>Hello</dd>` as `doc('https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml/sample-a.xml')/aa/bb` selects an element `<bb>sample-b.xml</bb>` and that way the following step `doc(resolve-uri(., base-uri(.)))` reads `https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml/sample-b.xml` and the steps `cc/dd` then select the `dd` element in that document.

In pure XPath 1 this is difficult, in XSLT 1 you might be able to implement the same with templates and the `document` function changing the context to the other document.

It is not clear to me, in what way you want to decide when a value of an element is a relative URI to be resolved/followed but perhaps a check like

```
doc('https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml/sample-a.xml')/aa/bb/(
  let $uri := resolve-uri(., base-uri(.)) 
  return if (doc-available($uri)) then doc($uri)/cc/dd else ())
```

suffices.

And there might be existing technologies like XPointer or XLink that kind of try to specify and implement such stuff.

Comment: Hello again, Martin.  Thank you for the answer.  I spent some time this morning working on a solution using https://github.com/keimpema/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard.  It looks like an excellent library and the code works.  It uses XInclude.  Unfortunately, as soon as I load the first document into XPathDocument it immediately follows and loads the XInclude.  I need it to be deferred.  Your solution with doc-available() may still be the way to go.  The key point is I don't know that <b> contains a pointer until I get to it.  I know it's a pointer by convention (say it starts with #).

Comment: The XInclude solution would be perfect.  The appearance of the XInclude would be the convention that lets me know the document is a relative URI.  However, I need the XPathDocument to wait until I try to select such a node before it tries to load the document.  In your solution, I always know to run the check at <bb>.  That won't work since I don't know beforehand.  Yes, the creator of <bb> knows, but the person writing the XPath shouldn't need to know.  I hope that clarifies the issue a bit.  The XInclude solution is so close if it would just lazy load.

Comment: It turns out that many years ago Microsoft did write something that works.  There is a dll called Microsoft.BizTalk.XPathReader.dll.  It is discussed in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms950778(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN